# Where should I store user-uploaded files and images in Phoenix/Elixir?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Users of my app should be able to upload files such as images. Where, in what folder, should I save those files? I'm not that familiar with deploying Elixir/Phoenix applications, but I want not to include those files into the output, packed file(s) that are generated when I'm deploying my application. In other words, I don't want to somehow statically embed uploaded images and files into my application. So where should I store them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this to **app/lib/app/endpoint.ex**

```
plug Plug.Static,
  at: "files/", from: "/var/www/app/files/", gzip: false
```

and store the uploaded files at `/var/www/app/files/`

The files will be served at **http://localhost:PORT/files/**

You can learn more at https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Static.html

Also, using something like nginx to serve the files in production environment may be a better option depending on your requirements.

Comment: ok, but how can I actually get the path of a certain image in a) view (html) b) controller?

Comment: also Static implies that all images will be stored in `"/var/www/app/files/"`. But I want only uploaded images to be stored there, static ones should be stored in a default location. Is it possible to do?

Comment: I mentioned that the files (images) will be served at **localhost/files/**.

e.g. If you were using port **4000** and had an image called **image.png**, I'll be available at **localhost:4000/files/image.png** if you followed my instructions.

Comment: Only uploaded images will be stored there. You already have default configuration for **Plug.Static** for real static files which is generated by Phoenix Framework.

Comment: I know. My question is "can I actually get the path of a certain image in a) view (html) b) controller? " That is, I'd not like to hardcode "files/" in a controller or view, I want to do something like `get_uploaded_image_url("image1.png")` which would return a full url of an image

Comment: I thought I was already being clear. Your `get_uploaded_image_url("image1.png")` would either return `localhost:4000/files/image.png` or `/var/www/app/files/image1.png` depending on your requirements.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You can add the path to your configurations if you don't want to want to type it out in your controller.

Comment: The question is, what that function really is. Does it exist?

Comment: `You can add the path to your configurations if you don't want to want` -- yes, but that be a repetition in code. In Rails we have a function "asset_path('image1.png')". Is there anything similar in Phoenix?

Comment: Your endpoint and your router helpers have static_path and static_url functions which you could use for this case.

Comment: @Omin The `plug Plug.Static` needs a comma: `plug Plug.Static,`

Comment: @Omin How do you handle the creation of the `/var/www/app/files/` directory, and do you have to configure special privileges for phoenix? I am having difficulty in understanding just where to create the folder...in my vm when deployed? Somewhere in the Phoenix project? I have very little knowledge about deployment yet.

Comment: By default, endpoint.ex specifies `plug Plug.static, at: "/", from: :app_name`. In dev, this makes it easy to write files to `./web/static/filename.png` and they get copied into `priv/static` by brunch and served. Can Phoenix save files on a relative path in production where they'll get served? If so, how?

Answer (score 10):

First of all there are two different options:

1. You can store your uploads locally
2. You can store them on external services, such as Amazon S3

Choosing the right option heavily depends on your business logic, number of users and requests and your deploying strategy (for example Heroku does not allow to store uploaded files on their dynos).

### Locally

So, the way store files locally is described in [this article](http://smashingboxes.com/blog/image-upload-in-phoenix). The short answer is:

```
# lib/my_app/endpoint.ex

plug Plug.Static,
  at: "/uploads", from: Path.expand("./uploads"), gzip: false
```

### Amazon

When dealing with Amazon S3, you would still use `arc` and the basic setup will remain the same as in the article above, but things are just slightly different and requires to reconfigure your application for a little bit:

Add `{:ex_aws, "~> 0.4"},` to deps.
And add to the config:

```
config :arc,
  bucket: "your-bucket",
  virtual_host: true

config :ex_aws,
  access_key_id: System.get_env("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"),
  secret_access_key: System.get_env("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"),
  s3: [
    scheme: "https://",
    host: "your-region.amazonaws.com",
    region: "your-region"
  ]
```

That's basically it. See [full installation instructions](https://github.com/CargoSense/ex_aws#getting-started).

P.S. Quite strange that [official docs](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/file-uploads) don't cover this topic, I guess it could be improved.

Comment: thanks. how can I get a path/url of an image from a) controller b) view?

Comment: See [arc docs](https://github.com/stavro/arc#url-generation). It is the same for view and controller.

Comment: where should "/uploads" be located, in the root of the project? if so, won't it be included into the output release generated file - I don't know what it's called - when deploying?

Comment: yes, the root folder is the place and no, only paths specified in `defp elixirc_paths(_),     do: ["lib", "web"]` go to `_build`.

Comment: but it then will be included in the compiled beam fie?

Comment: sorry, by "how can I get a path/url of an image from a) controller b) view?" I meant how to do that for an image in localhost.

Comment: @Johshi It really does not matter for `arc` what provider would you use, so the url generation will remain the same: `YourDefinition.url({model.avatar, model})`

Comment: you don't understand. I don't want to use arc because there's no need to use it because I want to upload and save files **locally**.

Comment: I don't see any reason not to use it, it is totally posible to store files locally. here's the source code for the local adapter in `arc`: https://github.com/stavro/arc/blob/master/lib/arc/storage/local.ex

Comment: There are many valid reasons not to use an additional library/package. My reason is that I don't want to add another layer of complexity for maintainability.